# Terminate threads created via executor service without reference to executor service

Tags: java, groovy, java-threads

I have executed a groovy in a running application, it creates few threads and submit some computation via executorService:

```
def executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize)
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync({ ->
    // work
}, executorService)
```

But I have forgot to call shutdown on the executorService, is there a way to get back a reference to the executorService, and stop the stuck up threads?

Comment: You mean to find & stop already running threads (invoked separately) using a new script?

Comment: Yes exactly @Rao